# Golang (gin) server is going down without any trace

Tags: go, go-gin

I tried making an API with gin.

```
router := gin.Default()
router.GET("/search", controllers.Search)
router.POST("/handshake/", controllers.Handshake)
router.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "message": "pong",
    })
})
router.Use(gin.Recovery())
router.Run(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", 8080))
```

I am creating the binary on my local machine running ubuntu 18.04 and distributing the binary to ubuntu 16.04 on AWS EC2. the service runs fine and stops suddenly without any trace of error or warning or panic on the log. very difficult to find out what's wrong?

Comment: [`Engine.Run()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.Run) returns an error, so start by printing that, e.g. `log.Printf("Server stopped, err: %v", router.Run(":8080"))`

Comment: Most likely you have a panic somewhere in a goroutine, not directly in a handler (otherwise gin.Recovery() would have taken care of it). See where you service writes stderr. That's where a panic would be logged. Where it is depends on how you run the service. If you run it as a script, make sure you redirect stderr somewhere. Upstart usually writes to /var/log/<your-service-name>.err. Don't remember where systemd writes it. But whatever you use, it should be in your system documentation.